# how to read and write data from multinode xml

Tags: c#, xml

how to read this kind of xml where there are multinodes. The format of the xml is:

```
<testresultdata>
  <testsetup>
    <testID>1</testID>
        <freqiency>80</freqiency>
        <level>1</level>
        <application>
              <appID>1</appID>
              <result>Pass</result>
        </application>
        <application>
              <appID>2</appID>
              <result>Fail</result>
        </application>
  </testsetup>
</testresultdata>
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post the XML up please? Use the {} button to show formatting. Which nodes do you need to read?

Answer (score 2):

It's not really clear what you mean... if you want to read all the `application` elements, for example, you could use:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("test.xml");
var query = doc.Descendants("application")
               .Select(x => new { AppID = (int) x.Element("appID"),
                                  Result = (string) x.Element("result") })
               .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple simple LINQ to XML examples:

```
    XDocument document = XDocument.Load("test.xml");
    var level = document.Descendants("testsetup")
                        .Where(x => x.Element("testID").Value == "1")
                        .Select(x => x.Element("level").Value)
                        .Single();


    var results = document.Descendants("application")
                          .Elements("result")
                          .Select(x => x.Value)
                          .ToList();
```

The first one reads the *single* value of `level` for `testsetup` with `testId` 1, the second gets you the results of *all* applications.

Comment: thx for the replys...but how to update and insert new data in this xml file?